# What is the "Self" object in Python?

Tags: python

I am not understanding the "Self" object in the following Python code:

```
>>> class Ancestor( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.name = "Ancestor"
    def getName( self ):
        return self.name


>>> class Base1( Ancestor ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.name = "Base1"
        super( Base1, self ).__init__( )
    def getName( self ):
        return self.name


>>> class Base2( Base1 ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.name = "Base2"
        super( Base2, self ).__init__( )
    def getName( self ):
        return self.name
    def getB1Name( self ):
        return super( Base2, self ).getName( )


>>> b2 = Base2( )
>>> b2.getName( )
'Ancestor'
>>> b2.getB1Name( )
'Ancestor'
```

I am not able to understand the result. I was expecting the result for b2.getName( ) to be "Base2" and the result for b2.getB1Name( ) to be "Base1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` refers to the *instance*, not the class.  You have only one instance, so all uses of `self` refer to the same object.  In `Base2.__init__` you set a name on this object.  You then call `super`, which invokes `Base1.__init__`, which sets a new name on the same object, overwriting the old one.

You can use [double-underscore attributes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) to achieve what you want, if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks, that is the explanation that I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

When you call the `super` function, you are basically jumping into the constructor of the `Ancestor` class and executing the code there. In the constructor, you set the name to `"Ancestor"`, overwriting the new name in the base classes.

If you make the call to `super` the first line in each constructor, it should return the correct name.

---

However, note that the `getB1Name` function in `B2` will always return the string `"Base2"` -- the `name` variable is simply overwritten and isn't "shadowed" in any way.

You *could* use double-underscore variables, which will automatically do some name-mangling so that the "shadowing" behavior is preserved, but in general, a more cleaner solution would be to simply use different variable names, and design the code so that you don't need two different versions of the same attribute floating around.

Comment: Putting the call to `super` first still won't do what he expects.  No matter what order you call the methods in, if you're using `self` you will only get one value for the attribute.  It can be either the lowest or highest in the hierarchy, but you won't get different values depending on which method you call.

Comment: Yeah, true. I didn't see the extra methods at first -- I was looking mostly at the constructor.